# Is there any way to build and run Windows containers via Rancher Desktop?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, rancher

I have installed Rancher Desktop application on Windows 10 and set it to use docker as container runtime. I was able to run simple commands on Windows with docker like,

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu sh
```

However, I could not find an option to switch it to run Windows container. Even pull command comes up with error

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
```

I tried to add --platform windows, like

```
docker pull --platform windows mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
```

but it responds that --platform windows is not recognised. I do understand that Rancher Desktop uses Kubernetes cluster in background to pull/build and run Linux Docker images/containers, but... is there way to make it run Windows images/containers? Docker Desktop is not an option !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to install Docker Desktop if you want to limit to command line operations  only - you can download binaries and set them up as stated in this article:

https://lippertmarkus.com/2021/09/04/containers-without-docker-desktop/

The most up to date binaries available here:
https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/

Do not forget to activate WSL /WSL2 before installation

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Rancher Desktop does not support Windows containers at present (Mar 2022), however there already a relevant issue tracking this feature on their GitHub repo:

https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/255

You may subscribe to the issue and see when will they release this feature.